# Better way of saying "this is because"

Tags: word-choice

I am writing the following

> Previous work on Topic Detection and Tracking (TDT) has achieved great
>   success on full length document, but the techniques has yet to be
>   fully implemented on microblogs. ***This is because*** the sources of TDT
>   are news articles which already contains news information and
>   structured...

I am trying to avoid joining them using a comma, as it will turn out to be a very lengthy sentence. At the same time, I wish to reduce "this is because" to a shorter version (preferably 1 word). I tried to remove it but it sounded odd and did not flow together well.

Can I get some suggestions, please? Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid this post may get closed as off-topic for asking about writing advice/ proof-reading. Even otherwise, there are several errors or grammar, which need your attention first.

Comment: @Kris, when I post at writers SE it says this is irrelevant, and when I post at English SE again it is off-topic. May I know which SE is the right place to ask for help (of word choice) or they both just not for that purpose?

Comment: I tend to appreciate long sentences like that, as they better convey the thought of what the author wants to convey. Older books (100 years+) tend to have a lot of them. Sadly it seems the modern mind cannot comprehend all the information at once, thus all sentences are shortened nowadays.

Comment: I would love writing long sentences, but it gets complicated to comprehend very soon. For many sentences, the only breakable point is a conjunction like becuase.

Answer (score 6):

There’s nothing wrong with ‘This is because . . .’, but an alternative would be ‘The reason is that . . .’ I don't know of any single word that would be suitable.

You might want to change *document* to *documents* and *has* to *have*.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

"Previous work on Topic Detection and Tracking (TDT) has achieved great success on full length document. However, the techniques has yet to be fully implemented on microblogs, because the sources of TDT are news articles which already contains news information and structured..."

?

Comment: This is the construction I would go for. However, I would remove the comma between *microblogs* and *because* to read *...implemented on microblogs because the sources...* The introduction of *however* at start gives you the opportunity to add more texture to your argument. For example *understandably*, *unfortunately*, *as of yet*, *for the time being* are all choices that would apply to specific cases.

Answer (score 2):

The actual answer to your question is *since*. But I agree with those posters who think that reducing the word count by two is not worth the long, clumsy sentence that will result.

Answer (score 1):

You could say "as it" or "as the" if you want a 'formal' approach. Ex: "He is correct, as the analysis proves." Or "It helps him stay a step in front of the game, as it tells him what the enemy is going to do."

Comment: Welcome to ELU!  I don't understand how your examples address the given question.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest: [Hence](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hence)

> The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language
>
> hence  (hns)  adv.
>   1.     a. For this reason; therefore: handmade and hence expensive.

Comment: *Hence* is actually the opposite of what's being asked.